# Check if content of index equals content of next index

Tags: python, list

```
array = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
new_array = [x for x in array if array[array.index(x)] != array[array.index(x) + 1]]
print(new_array)
```

Hi, I'm trying to write a program that will check if a content of an index (example: list[0]) equals to next index and if not append the number that differs and I tried to use a new skill I learned which is list comprehension and I don't quite understand why doesn't it work how it should work

To make it more clear what I mean is if I am given an array with all numbers the same except one number which in this case is two I want to append it in a list I also added a picture to make it even more clear

[image]

Comment: expected output and the problem you mentioned completely different

Comment: Please edit your post and add the error message

Comment: List comprehension is not the best choice for your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simple one liner

```
print(a[0] if a.count(a[0]) == 1 else min(set(a).difference(a[:1])))
```

**Note:** I'm using `min()` to just to get the element from set.

**Output:**

```
>>> a=[1, 1, 2]
>>> print(a[0] if a.count(a[0]) == 1 else min(set(a).difference(a[:1])))
2
>>> a = [17, 17, 3, 17, 17, 17, 17]
>>> print(a[0] if a.count(a[0]) == 1 else min(set(a).difference(a[:1])))
3
```

Comment: It did work but I'm an absolute beginner so that took a bit to understand but thank you for the solution

Comment: After I reviewed a little more of your code and fully understood how it works it's a very clever solution, you're a genius man

Answer (score 1):

`IndexError: list index out of range` means you are passing an index that isn't present in the list. And that error is raised in this part:

```
array[array.index(x) + 1]
```

When x is the last element error is raised. Because there is no index after the last element. In your case, using list comprehension isn't the best choice, you should prefer for loop.

Comment: I know just wanted to use list comprehension since I learned how to do it only a few days ago so wanted to practice

Comment: Okay, I got your point. Prefer using list comprehension when the result doesn't rely on other elements for one particular point, the other times it is okay to use list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

it may help you:

```
list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
for i, j in enumerate(list[:-1]):
    if j  == list[i+1]: 
       #dosomething
```